# Eigen values of $A. \operatorname{adj}(A)$ where $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ is adjoint matrix of A are real

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Eigen values of $A\cdot\operatorname{adj}(A)$ where $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ is the adjoint matrix of a non-singular matrix A are real.

This is a question asked in an exam. I have a doubt that info is incomplete.

Let $lambda$ be eigenvalue of A such that $Ax=\lambda x $

This gives,

$A \cdot\operatorname{adj}(A) x = |A| x$ as $\operatorname{adj}(A) = \frac{A^{-1}}{|A|}$

Let $B = A\cdot\operatorname{adj}(A)$ then $B$ is hermitian only if $B^{\theta} = B$. It means

B = $A\cdot\operatorname{adj}(A) = |A|I$, For  $B^{\theta} = B$, $|A|$ has to be real. Only then $B=A\cdot\operatorname{adj}(A)$ is hermitian, which means given matrix has eigen values. But in exam I assumed this condition that $|A| $ is real. But is there any way to do this without assuming it as real.

Comment: @amd corrected. Pls check now

Comment: Are you sure adj means adjugate and not adjoint (i.e. conjugate transpose)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether you mean "adjoint" or "adjugate".
(1) Assume you mean "adjoint". Then if $A{\rm adj}(A)x=\lambda x$, we can write $$\lambda \left<x,x\right> =\left<x, A{\rm adj}(A)x\right>=\left<Ax, Ax \right>,$$ where $\left<\cdot,\cdot\right>$ is a Hermitian scalar product. As $\left<x,x\right>>0$ and $\left<Ax, Ax \right>\ge 0$ , $\lambda$ is real and nonnegative.

(2) Assume you mean "adjugate". Then $A{\rm adj}(A) = (\det A)I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. Clearly the only eigenvalue is $\det A$. This has no reason to be real unless $A$ is real.

Comment: madam in my text book, adjoint matrix is given as adjugate matrix in ur explanation. If it is complex conjugate everything goes straightforward. Wiki also says adjoint or some times adjugate. Can u pls elaborate?

Comment: @kusuma pls see here -- https://nptel.ac.in/courses/122104018/node29.html

Comment: Oh, I see. Your text is using slightly older terminology. The word "adjoint" also sometimes means what I called the "adjugate", but this is not common in recent publications. See also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix (the introduction mentions different terminology).

Answer (score 5):

If adj denotes the *adjugate*, then
$$
A\operatorname{adj}A=(\det A)I
$$
(with $I$ the suitable identity matrix) is diagonal, so its only eigenvalue is $(\det A)$.

If $A$ is supposed to be a complex matrix, its determinant may be not real.

Your exercise is probably about $AA^*$, where $A^*$ is the *adjoint* of $A$, that is, the conjugate transpose. Since $AA^*$ is Hermitian, the eigenvalues are surely real.

Indeed, if $B=B^*$ (that is, $B$ is Hermitian) and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B$, then $Bv=\lambda v$ for some column vector $v\ne0$. Then
$$
v^*Bv=v^*(\lambda v)=\lambda(v^*v)
$$
On the other hand,
$$
v^*Bv=v^*B^*v=(Bv)^*v=(\lambda v)^*v=\bar{\lambda}v^*v
$$
Since $v^*v\ne0$, we conclude $\lambda=\bar{\lambda}$ is real.

Comment: Sir in my text book, adjoint matrix is given as adjugate matrix in ur explanation. If it is complex conjugate everything goes straightforward. Wiki also says adjoint or some times adjugate. Can u pls elaborate?

Comment: @Magneto What language is the book written in?

Comment: english.........

Comment: https://nptel.ac.in/courses/122104018/node29.html
Pls see this here.

Comment: @Magneto The page call *adjoint* what's commonly called *adjugate*. The product $A\operatorname{adj}(A)$ is *always* a diagonal matrix, where the diagonal has entries equal to $\det A$; so its only eigenvalue is $\det A$. The exercise makes little sense if this adjoint/adjugate is used; more significant, as I said, is to consider the *adjoint* also called *Hermitian transpose*.